# SwiftUI: Hidden NavigationBar blocks UI

Tags: swiftui, navigationbar, navigationview

I am using a NavigationView to navigate between views. As I don't want to use the NavigationBar, I am hiding it. Unfortunately, the area where the NavigationBar was (it is hidden) is still blocking the UI. A button there cannot be tapped.

How can I fix this?

```
// First View
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                
                Text("Title")
                
                Spacer()
                
                NavigationLink(destination: View2()) {
                    Text("Next")
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
// Second View: Here the button cannot be tapped
struct View2: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    print("this button doesn't work")
                }, label: {
                    Text("Do something")
                })
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.top, 50)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to used second `NavigationView` - it is wrong, there should  be only one root navigation view which manages navigation stack in this case.

[image: demo]

So here is fixed view (child one)

```
struct View2: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                print("this button doesn't work")
            }, label: {
                Text("Do something")
            })
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.top, 50)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```

Tested with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2

*Note: as you hide navigation but you don't need mode modifier as well, so removed `.navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)`. Just for your info.*